# ¿Cómo realizar correctamente un split en funcion del salto de linea "\n"?

Tags: nodejs, string, split

Intenté realizarlo en **node** con la siguiente funcion.

```
const separarString = (value) => value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/,-1);
```

donde value es `"Tu codigo \nno funciona"`, obtengo el resultado deseado.

```
["Tu codigo","no funciona"]
```

Pero al imprirlo me muestra

```
Tu codigo
,no funciona
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El split está funcionando de manera correcta. Si lees bien [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) te darás cuenta de que la función `split` no devuelve una string, devuelve un array... Por eso al hacer `console.log` se te imprime en ese formato que ves (con la coma).

```js
const mensaje = "Tu codigo \nno funciona";

const separarString = (value) => value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, -1);

console.log("Formato de array que incluye coma y corchetes cuadrados:")
console.log(separarString(mensaje));


console.log("\nUtilizando map para hacer la impresión:")
separarString(mensaje).map((palabra) => console.log(palabra))
```

### UPDATE

```js
const mensaje="Tu codigo \nno funciona";

const separarString = (value) => value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/,-1);


const Lista = (label, value) => {
    const list = separarString(value);
    return `
        <div class="item">
            <strong>${label}</strong>
            <div class="item-value">${
              Array.isArray(list) && list.map((el) => `<p>${el}</p>`)
            }</div>
        </div>
    `;
};

console.log("Utilizando map (devolviendo un array");
console.log(Lista("etiqueta",mensaje));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const ListaForEach = (label, value) => {
    const list = separarString(value);
    let contenido = "";
    Array.isArray(list) && list.forEach((el) => contenido+=`<p>${el}</p>`);
    return `
        <div class="item">
            <strong>${label}</strong>
            <div class="item-value">${
             contenido
            }</div>
        </div>
    `;
};

console.log("Utilizando forEach para generar una string");
console.log(ListaForEach("etiqueta",mensaje));
```

El problema es que el `map` devuelve tambien un `array`,  no tiene que ver con la librería, te recomiendo usar una `string` para almacenar el resultado final.

Comment: claro, la impresion la hago con map al resultado.

Comment: No logro comprender cuál es problema que tienes. Qué es lo qué no está bien a la hora de imprimir el resultado?

Comment: hay una "," en la impresión.

Comment: Te hice un ejemplo usando `map`, no aparece la coma.

Comment: puede ser un problema muy especifico, dado que solo aparece cuando utilizo [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme) al momento de crear el pdf se imprime la coma.

Comment: Te actualice la respuesta, no es un problema de la librería.

Comment: Ok entiendo map me retornaba un array nuevamente por eso la coma. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO

```
const separarString = (value) => value.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/,-1);

const Lista = (label, value) => {
    const list = separarString(value);
    return `
        <div class="item">
            <strong>${label}</strong>
            <div class="item-value">${
              Array.isArray(list) && list.map((el) => `<p>${el}</p>`)
            }</div>
        </div>
    `;
};
```